# How to Make a One-Time Space Adjustment in the Display of Two Specified Consecutive Footnotes

Tags: spacing, footnotes, footmisc

I am typesetting a document in which the type of text varies that is to be footnoted. In some cases, it seems that the standard spacing between consecutive footnotes is insufficient.

I would like to make, if possible, one-time adjustments to the spacing between two specified footnotes, and then revert back to the original spacing.

For example, consider

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{footmisc}

    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    A sentence.\footnote{First footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Second footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Third footnote}
    A sentence.\footnote{Fourth footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Fifth footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Sixth footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Seventh footnote.}
    \end{document}
```

which produces the footnote display:

[image]

QUESTION: If I wanted, say to increase the standard spacing 50% between, say, the 3rd and 4th footnotes, and then revert back to the standard spacing beginning with the fifth footnote--- How may this be accomplished?

Thank you.

Comment: For one time adjusting try: Another sentence.`\footnote{Third footnote \vspace*{0.2\baselineskip}}`

Comment: @Simon Dispa Thank you for your very helpful comment. Perhaps you will consider posting it as an answer so that others may more readily benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For one time adjusting only:** (add vertical space as desired, try `\vspace*{10\baselineskip}`)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{footmisc}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    A sentence.\footnote{First footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Second footnote}
    \footnote{Third footnote \vspace*{0.3\baselineskip}} % changed <<<<
    A sentence.\footnote{Fourth footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Fifth footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Sixth footnote}
    Another sentence.\footnote{Seventh footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you again for this very nice, simple answer.